# On Android, is there any way to disable a Spinner's long-press behavior?

Tags: android, spinner, long-press

The default spinner behavior is that when it's "closed", longpressing on it will "open" it and show you the dropdown view. I find this behavior to be potentially very problematic for the user. For example, if they're trying to scroll something on the screen, and happen to "grab" a spot that has a spinner, then instead of scrolling, it'll open the dropdown view after a second or so, and the user is basically left with their finger on one of the dropdown options (which they can now accidentally press).

So, I'd like to disable that long-press behavior, and have the spinner "open" when only it's clicked, and not long-pressed. Is that possible?

Comment: `m_spinner.setLongClickable(false);` might help you out here

Comment: Yeah, I tried that first, but it has no effect on a Spinner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I've figured out a relatively easy way to do this, even though it's not very elegant. Basically, I created a transparent overlay view on top of the Spinner, and set it to have an OnClickListener that just triggers a Spinner's click.

**XML:**

```
    <Spinner 
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="40dip" />

    <View android:id="@+id/spinner_overlay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/spinner" 
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/spinner"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/spinner" 
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/spinner"  />
```

**Java:**

```
        View spinnerOverlay = findViewById(R.id.spinner_overlay);
        spinnerOverlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                spinner.performClick();
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 8):

If you only need to restore the standard click behaviour, this is a simpler and more compact version of [Jordi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27923912/2291104):

```
spinner.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                v.performClick();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

#### Further thoughts

This behaviour has also been annoying me. After investigation, it seems like it has a name: *drag to open*. You can see how it's defined in the source of the [`AppCompatSpinner#onTouchEvent()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatSpinner.java#410) method.

Some problems I see with this forced behaviour (and the reason for which some people want to disable it):

1. It allows the user to selects disabled values in the spinner. By long-pressing, dragging and releasing, you can select values which would not even be selectable with a normal interaction (click-to-open + click-to-select)
2. As a consequence of #1, it can also make Espresso test fail very easily. Indeed, in Espresso, the duration of a click is rather unstable and one tap can quickly turn into a long-press-and-select-interaction.
3. Finally, the biggest problem here is that there is no method / XML attribute to disable the "drag to open" behaviour...

#### Let's have it fixed!

I've opened a ticket related to this on the AOSP issue tracker: [#228953](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=228953). Feel free to follow it, or to comment if I missed anything.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried android:longClickable="false" in xml yet?

or try something like this:

```
spinner.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        private static final int MAX_CLICK_DISTANCE = 15;
        private static final int MAX_CLICK_DURATION = 1000;
        private long pressStartTime;
        private float pressedX;
        private float pressedY;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                    pressStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    pressedX = event.getX();
                    pressedY = event.getY();
                    break;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                long pressDuration = System.currentTimeMillis() - pressStartTime;
                if (pressDuration < MAX_CLICK_DURATION && distance(pressedX, pressedY, event.getX(), event.getY()) < MAX_CLICK_DISTANCE) {
                     //when long clicked.
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        return false;
}
```

Comment: If you override a spinner's OnTouchListener, it stops working altogether

Comment: Not with mine, I use this function on a imageslider. The sliding controls from the super still work, only when I click under 1 second and x range it will trigger an onClick. If it doesn't fit this range it will just use the parent function.

**Try pressDuration > MAX_CLICK_DURATION. This will do nothing when you press longer then 1 second (LongClick).**

Comment: it has nothing to do with duration -- you're overriding the OnTouchListener, and you're not processing any events that would normally be there.

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but maybe still useful for someone:

Setting an `OnLongClickListener` that returns `true` in `onLongClick` prevents an (unintentional) opening of the `Spinner`, because it works as if the callback consumed the long click as stated in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html).

```
spinner.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

The only downside is, that the spinner would still have the onTouch animation when long clicked.

Answer (score 0):

This is my implementation to prevent spinner opened when user scrolling (using kotlin)

```
spinner.setOnTouchListener { view, event ->
    when (event.action) {
        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
            return@setOnTouchListener true
        }
        MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
            return@setOnTouchListener true
        }
        MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
            view.performClick()
            return@setOnTouchListener false
        }
        else -> return@setOnTouchListener true
    }
}
```

Basically, this code will return true in all **MotionEvent** except **MotionEvent.ACTION_UP** so that spinner will only opened when users lift their finger from spinner.

When users scroll the screen and lift their finger, **MotionEvent.ACTION_UP** on spinner's parent **ScrollView** will be triggered instead of spinner's **MotionEvent.ACTION_UP** ([android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP not detected when scollview kicks in](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28188937/17383687)), so the code above will not be triggered and spinner won't be opened accidentally while scrolling.